# Can an American birth certificate be redeemed for money?

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds

Can an American birth certificate be redeemed for money? Why is it printed on bond paper?

Comment: To partially answer your second question: https://skeptoid.com/blog/2017/01/06/birth-certificate-bond/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with personal finance.

Comment: @PeteB. I would say that this *is* on-topic, because it is asking about the truth behind a very specific conspiracy theory involving money.

Comment: @trashpanda Oh my god. There seem to be such… lightly brained people in all countries. It's more or less the same kind of guys which claim that Germany is a LLC and we Germans are their personnel. Such nonsense hurts. (But, nevertheless, is interesting to read.)

Comment: That link will answer your first question now that it's been edited and switched

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for value (No levy due). The fringe on this flag invalidates the feudal jurisdiction of the Admiralty Court, which is disclaimed.

Comment: I had not heard this theory, and when I read the title, I thought the question was going to be about selling a birth certificate to an identity theft ring.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Clearly, the bond value is only redeemable for a publicly registered legal personality created by the state.  As long as you are not lost at sea, it would simply mean that you need recognize that personality under common law.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Given this is related to sov-cit issues, I would argue that means it deserves a serious answer, not a vote to be closed.  A terrifying number of people believe in this nonsense and dismissing their questions when they seek real answers only plays into conspiracy theory.

Comment: @Chuu I wasn't actually VTC'ing the question, just posting stereotypical sov-cit screed to be funny.

Comment: Most people would probably have to pay the government to take it back since their net worth is likely negative. This means that most people cannot afford to sell it even if it was "legal".

Comment: There's no such thing as an "American" birth certificate.  They are done by the individual states.  And the one I have is printed on what appears to be old-fashioned fax/thermal copier paper.

Comment: @jamesqf as discussed below, the one you have is a copy, so it may well have been literally a fax.

Comment: My American birth certificate *isn't* printed on bond paper.  It's just a piece of regular paper that came out of a photocopy machine and was then signed and sealed by a municipal officer.  @Kevin as I understand it the document is in fact a birth certificate; it is a copy of a birth *record.*  But maybe terminology varies from one jurisdiction to the next.

Comment: you know bonds can be written on anything....

Comment: @BenMiller - do you want to edit, or comment on why you feel this is on topic?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I’d be happy to. Imagine that there was truth to this, and that an American birth certificate entitled you to a cash payout. I think we’d all agree that in that scenario a question about it would be an on-topic personal finance question. So if this question would be on-topic if the answer was “yes,” why should it be off-topic just because the answer is “no”? We don’t close questions for ignorance; the reason people ask any question is that they don’t know the answer.

Comment: @BenMiller this is off-topic, and belongs on Skeptics.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Skeptics.SE.

Comment: @RonJohn The fact that a question might be allowed on another site does not automatically mean it is off-topic here, so your stated off-topic reason is invalid. I believe the question is on-topic for the reasons in my above comment.

Answer (score 67):

> Why is an American birth certificate on bond paper?

Because it is an important document which needs to survive for a whole human lifetime. So it gets printed on paper which is thicker and of a higher quality than usual photocopier paper. This style of paper is traditionally called "[bond paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_paper)" because it was often used for bond certificates when physical financial instruments were still a thing. But just because something is printed on bond paper doesn't mean it's a bond. This kind of paper is used for many other purposes. For arts and crafts, application letters, participation certificates, greeting cards, menus in fancy restaurants, business cards, etc. [You can buy that stuff on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=bond+paper).

And the reverse isn't true either. There is no regulation which says that physical bond certificates (if they even exist at all - most bonds only exist on electronic ledgers) must be printed on specific paper to be valid.

> Can you redeem it for money?

There might be some shady people who might be very interested in assuming a false identity of an US citizen. They might be very intersted in buying a valid birth certificate. But willingly selling your birth certificate and thus your identity to a potential criminal would be a move which would be both illegal and extremely stupid.

Comment: The birth certificate actually doesn't need to survive a whole lifetime, this is a misconception by many people. The actual birth certificate is never provided to the individual, it is filled out by the hospital and sent into the county registrar. They file it, which was historically on microfilm but now electronically, and issue you a _certified copy_, on bond paper with a seal. A copy is the only version you will ever get, and you can always order another for $20-30. Many people don't realize this so they hang on to their original tattered copy, when you can send away for a new one.

Comment: I would strongly object that it was HISTORICALLY on microfilm. Chances are that there were birth certificates BEFORE microfilm was actually invented. Which then goes back to "paper form to survive a lifetime".

Comment: @TomTom Before the microfilm era, county records were entered into a [row in a large book](https://s1.sos.mo.gov/records/archives/archivesdb/birthdeath/images/births.jpg). A certificate was issued [based on the information in the book](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1912_Birth_Certificate_Ken_Baker.jpg), so fundamentally the system worked the same as our electronic records today.

Comment: Except with no proper communication people would more often get paper certificates and those would have to survive quite some time and abuse, i would assume.

Comment: @user71659: Granted it's just one data point, but my experience is that the certified copy is not on bond paper, but whatever paper the copiers/printers of the time used.

Comment: @jamesqf Apparently, the [Illegal Immigration Reform and Immigrant Responsibility Act of 1996](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/ocomm/ilink/0-0-0-10948.html#0-0-0-1457) required safety paper, among other things, as an anti-fraud measure.

Comment: @user71659 so does that mean my birth certificate from before that act is no longer valid?  I am pretty sure I've used it since then, but maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: @TomTom, in the US, standardized civil birth registration and the related certificates started in 1902.  Microfilm was invented in the 1850s, and saw widespread use starting in the 1920s.  Yes, there was a brief period when civil birth registrations were likely to be done in ledger format, but microfilm is by far the most common pre-electronic method.  (Prior to about the mid-1800s, birth records were generally managed by religious authorities, not civil ones, to the extent that anyone cared about them.)

Comment: @phoog I think it depends on who's accepting the copy. For example, the State Department's passport service (under "2. Provide Evidence of US Citizenship") [list a number of requirements](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/apply-in-person.html)

Comment: @user71659 the county sent *original* birth certificates to us after our children were born.

Comment: @user71659: I doubt very much that YOU will get a birth certificate.  Your parents might - not being one myself, I wouldn't know - but a lot can happen before you reach a point where you'd care about it.

Answer (score 38):

You are referring to a specific conspiracy theory called the "redemption movement" involving the United States government, bankruptcy, and Jewish bankers.

Of course, there is [no truth to this theory](https://skeptoid.com/blog/2017/01/06/birth-certificate-bond/).  (Thanks, @trashpanda, for the link in the comments.)  Your birth certificate is not redeemable for money from either the United States government or any international bank, no matter which kind of paper it happens to be printed on.

Comment: I read the linked article, and if I follow the explanation there, the USA has issued bonds with their citizens as guarantee, so as a US individual you'd actually have to pay a million dollar to the "international banker" holding your bond, to get your freedom back. So not only is this total nonsense, it's actually upside down total nonsense.

Comment: Is "_the redemption movement_" an actual conspiracy theory?  Just seems like some of the more outrageous conspiracy theories are themselves hoaxes, invented for entertainment.

Comment: @Nat I think it's somewhere in between. I think this stuff is intentionally thought up, not to be believed, but to trip up the legal system so the inventor can get out of paying taxes. Those that they pass it on to may actually believe in it though.